# Querying max of timestamp from PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, select, optimization

Assume there are 3 rows in a PostgreSQL table named `tracker`. I want to fetch the latest updated record alone. Please help me achieving it.

```
(issue_id,priority,ingest_date)
(1,1,"2015-01-27 00:00:00")
(1,2,"2015-01-28 00:00:00")
(1,3,"2015-01-29 00:00:00")
```

I tried giving

```
select * 
from tracker 
where ingest_date = (select max(ingest_date) from tracker);
```

This works fine for me.
But is there any better way I can query the DB?

Thanks in advance.

I want something like

```
select * 
from etl_change_fact 
where ingest_date = max(ingest_date);
```

But I get this error

```
**ERROR: aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause
**
```

Comment: If you have an index on `ingest_date` your first query is probably the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I agree with horse. Assuming an index, the subquery will turn which by most other methods will be an index or table scan into an index seek. Very efficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows. Just select the latest record...

```
 SELECT * from tracker ORDER BY ingest_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

This query will always return only one record.
Your query can return multiple rows if ingest_date contains duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the `ingest_date` is unique (i.e., there is only one row which is the latest), you could use a `fetch first` clause:

```
SELECT      *
FROM        tracker
ORDER BY    ingest_date DEXC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

If this assumption can't be made, you could use the `rank` window function to return all the "latest" records:

```
SELECT issue_id, priority, ingest_date
FROM   (SELECT issue_id, priority, ingest_date, 
               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ingest_date DESC) AS rk
        FROM   tracker)
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: It's really not necessary to create a window for a problem this simple, `select * from table where col = (select max(col) from table)` will result in a more efficient query plan.